# How to restore DNN Backup

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have taken DNN 6 backup in the following ways

1. Copy the DNN folder from C:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. Take Sqlserver 2008 Enterprise edition database backup

When I try to restore it, I am getting error:

> Connection Error(s): Index #: 0 Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   Class: 14 Number: 18456 Message: Sql login failed

I am using the following link for restoration:

```
.../Install/InstallWizard.aspx
```

Note !!! When i change the database and username, it will install the fresh installation but not restoring backup database.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about needing to run the /InstallWizard.aspx to perform a restore.  The first step is to get the files laid down in the Windows directory you want, and then get the IIS setup and pointed properly ensuring that you have the right security access (Depending on your version of IIS) to the files. If you get all that right you will be good to go from a file perspective.

As far as SQL Server you will need to do a manual database restore and as Mitch says create a new account that will have access to the database - You will need to change both database access statements the web.config to specify the new user. (standard and legacy if they both exist)  Finally, make sure that SQL server is configured in Mixed Mode Authentication if you are specifying a SQL user.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answer here will depend on where/how you are restoring the database.

If you take a database from one server to the other, the user account does NOT come with it from a server login perspective.  So after restoring the database, you will need to create a new user account for managing the access to the database.